# Norwegian in natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, babel

I have a small problem with some of my citations. I am writing my thesis in Norwegian, so the package `natbib` doesn't cite my sources the right way when there are two authors because of the incompatibility with Norwegian, eg. `\cite{a source with two authors}` produces this output

> ["Name X" and "Name Y" (xxxx)]

My problem is that I can't have "and" in my text, because that is not Norwegian. What I would like to have is an output that said `\cite{a source with two authors}`

> "Name X" og "Name Y" (xxxx)

The word "og" is the Norwegian word for "and". I tried with `hyperref`, but I didn't work with making references to a source, only labels.

So far I've made a pretty bad work around to fix the problem by using `\nocite` to write what I would like the outcome to be, e.g. authors separated by "og" and not "and".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

What should I do in order to change the element of connection when `\citep{}` a source with exactly two authors? What is the command that define it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you use? The bibliography style that's in use, rather than `natbib`, is what determines which conjunctive particle (and, og, et, und, y, ...) is inserted between the authors' names.

Comment: I did a short work-around by using \deficealias in the natbib package. This way I could configure some of the references that said "Young AND Jones, 1950", into "Young OG Jones, 1950".